# Why should I rebuild Caffe each time I want to use a new package?

Tags: python, package, installation, ubuntu-14.04, caffe

I am very new to Ubuntu and I just started learning Caffe. The question might come stupid as I have no idea about how 'make' command works.

Anyway, I installed Caffe following the instruction in this link: [Caffe Installation](https://gist.github.com/titipata/f0ef48ad2f0ebc07bcb9) and everything works fine for me.

However, recently I decided to try two packages which are based on Caffe: [Faster R-CNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) and [MS-CNN](https://github.com/zhaoweicai/mscnn). In their installation instructions are mentioned that I need to '*make*' Caffe and pycaffe. It might make sense as both of them added some new layers to Caffe. But do I have to really make Caffe and pycaffe again or is there any other way to install these packages? 
Then what should I do with my previous Caffe folder? do I have to just remove it? Then how can I have both packages simultaneously when each has its own copy of caffe?

P/S: when I want to make any of these Caffe, the $PYTHONPATH$ should point to the python folder of that caffe or it generates an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to 'make'  caffe for each installation. I don't know of any other way. This is because each version might have different layers.

You can have multiple versions of caffe on your system. There is no need to remove one in order to make another. You'll just have to change the $PYTHONPATH$ to whichever caffe you want to use.